# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this question has been asked a lot before, but I can't seem to find any place in my code where I'm binding my list a to an integer value. I've changed all my variable names but to no avail.

Here's the entire code I'm running:

```
import sys
def powerset(a):
# returns a list of all subsets of the list a
if (len(a) == 0):
    return [[]]
else:
    allSubsets = [ ]
    for subset in powerset(a[1:]):
        allSubsets += [subset]
        allSubsets += [[a[0]] + subset]
    return allSubsets

if __name__ == '__main__':
  no_test = int(sys.stdin.readline())
  for i in xrange(no_test):
    xor_res = 0
    len = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    numbers_array = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
    numbers = []
    for i in numbers_array:
        numbers.append(i)
    maxset = powerset(numbers)
    for set in maxset:
        if len(set) != 0:
            temp = 0
            for i in set:
                temp = temp^i
        xor_res = xor_res ^ temp
    print xor_res
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "solution.py", line 24, in <module>maxset = powerset(numbers)File "solution.py", line 6, in powerset  if (len(a) == 0):TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Can someone please tell me what's going wrong here? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You've created a variable called `len` that shadows the built in function `len()`:

```
len = int(sys.stdin.readline())
```

When you try to call the `len` function throughout your code, the interpreter finds the `len` variable first and tries to call it like a function. Since it's an `int`, this can't be done and we see the error.

To solve your problem, call your variable something different. In general, avoid creating variables with names like "len", "list", "map", etc, since using these names shadows the built in ones.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Batman If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark under the vote counter. I'd greatly appreciate it.